# Facebook custom tab not expanding in IE7 or IE8

Tags: facebook, tabs, height

Ideally I want my Facebook custom tab to expand with the content - I seem to be able to get this working OK in all the latest browsers, but not when it comes to IE7 and IE8.

The pages just cuts off early, hiding the rest of the content. I'm using the following js code right now:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}

function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
```

And my CSS:

```
#container {
background: url('../images/background.jpg');
height: 100%;
position:relative;
clear:both;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

My canvas height is set to fluid.

Any ideas/tips would be much appreciated!

Thanks
MK

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a canvas app or a page tab app?
If the latter, the width is 520px - there is no fluid option for page tab apps

Comment: OK, I think I may have things a little confused. Right now I have both of these options selected under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" - 

    "App on Facebook" and 
    "Page Tab"

I have a feeling I have it set up as a page tab when I want a canvas app. 
Can these be added down the left hand side of the page (eg underneath photos etc) and link between each other like tabs? But if I don't have it set up correctly then why is it working in all the other modern browsers to 100% height?

Comment: A Page Tab app can be attached to a Page and displayed there as a tab along with the wall, info tabs etc. - these are fixed width.
A canvas app ('App on Facebook') can be accessed at apps.facebook.com/something - these can be made fluid width in the app settings

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's a pain, I was hoping to be able to have it fluid width but also selectable down the side like "Info". Otherwise surely it's a pain to actually locate it if you're browsing the page?